# Logical implication

Tags: logic

I'm stuck with a logic problem like this

> I eat ice cream if I am sad.
>
> I am not sad.
>
> Therefore I am not eating ice cream.

Is this conclusion logical? The first sentence can be understood both like "ice cream $\implies$ sad" and vice versa. He stated that he is not sad but does that not mean that he is not eating ice cream ? I'm confused.

Comment: so you are saying that this statement is not logical then

Comment: "I eat ice cream if I am sad” does not say that I eat ice cream "only if" I am sad.  Maybe I eat ice cream every day. Maybe when I'm sad I eat ice cream because I'm sad, and when I'm happy I eat ice cream because I'm happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Argument:**

> "I eat ice cream if I am sad. I am not sad.Therefore I am not eating ice cream."

Whenever you are stuck in an argument, try represent it in proper symbolism:

**Glossary**:

$E \equiv $ 'I eat ice cream'

$S \equiv $ 'I am sad'

Then we can represent your above argument like this:

> 1. $S \to E$
> 2. $\neg S$
>
> $\therefore \neg E$

Now is this a **valid argument**? (Recall the definition of a valid argument!) For instance, Let the statements (1) and (2) be true. Can $\neg E$ be false?

Comment: no i dont think ¬E can be false

Comment: @Gummy What about have a look at its truth table? $$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
S & E & S\to Q & \neg S & \neg E\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1&  0 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 &0 &1\\ \hline
0 & 1 & \color{blue}{1} &\color{blue}{1} &\color{red}{0}\\ \hline
0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} &\color{blue}{1} &\color{blue}{1}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: yeah I understand this, but how do you know when an argument is valid or not. Sorry, my 1st language is not Eng, so I might a have a little problem at understanding. So yes not E can be false

Comment: @Gummy Roughly, an argument is valid if and only if (iff) it's not be the case that it's premises are true and the conclusion false. So now what can we say about this argument? And don't worry about your English, take your time :)

Comment: so this argument is not valid since we statement (1) and (2) are premises and they are both true and the conclusion of ¬E  is false .Thus this argument is not valid ?

Comment: @Gummy Perfect! Good work! So, in your words, this conclusion is not "logical" (= it does not follow from the premises).

Comment: yes !, thank you but I got it wrong in the assessed worksheet. Anyway it's all good. Thank you so much for the patient and help.

Answer (score 4):

In logic, there is a difference between *[implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence)* ($a \implies b$) and *[equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)* ($a \iff b$). The word "if" (without "only") usually means the first one:

"I am sad" $\implies$ "I eat ice cream"

If "I am sad" is false, we cannot logically say anything about "I eat ice cream". It may be true or false. This makes sense, because being sad is not the only reason for eating ice cream.

See also: [Denying the antecedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent)

Comment: so what if it has the word "only" in it ? Does it means that "SAD imples ICE CREAM" ?

Comment: @Gummy Yes, "only" would make them equivalent and imply each other

Comment: how can "only" imply each other ? Since you cant say:" I am sad only if I eat ice-cram" but you have to say:"I eat ice cream only if I am sad". "SAD" is the necessary condition and "Ice cream" is the sufficient condition ? So SAD must implies Ice cream ? NO ? Please I suck and I know.

Comment: @Gummy In a logical equivalence, there are no necessary or sufficient conditions.

Comment: but i dont think they are logically equivalent to each other

Answer (score 3):

$P\implies Q$ does not necessarily mean $Q \implies P$

But what does this mean exactly?

Well think of it like this.

> All Carrots are vegetables

but this doesn't mean that

> All vegetables are Carrots